# How to validate a VM has powered off?

Tags: powershell, vmware, vsphere, powercli

I'm powering off a VM using the `Stop-VMGuest` cmdlet, and I can monitor the powerstate of the VM, but I noticed that when `Stop-VMGuest` is executed, the powerstate changes immediately to `PoweredOff`. This would be fine if it was accurate, but the issue is that, when I open the console to the VM, the VM is still powering off and going through it's normal graceful shutdown steps.

Is there a way to verify that the VM has completely shutdown after running the cmdlet `Stop-VMGuest`?

Answer (score 0):

Once a guest power off is initiated there is nothing in VMware that tracks the guest status.

Why not just do something simple such as, ping or test-connection to verify you can no longer connect to the machine?